# Block type not working in layout/catalog.xml

Tags: layout, blocks

I'm working with the AW Mobile2 extension which works fine more or less. 
I notice the product image doesn't show up on the product view page. Unfortunately I do not see any related issue in the log files like "exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Invalid block type'".

Debugging turned out out that Magento doesn't show the image because of the block type:

app/design/frontend/aw_mobile2/iphone/layout/catalog.xml

```
[Does not work]
<block type="aw_mobile2/catalog_product_view_media" name="product.info.media" as="media" template="catalog/product/view/media.phtml"/>

[Works]
<block type="catalog/product_view_media" name="product.info.media" as="media" template="catalog/product/view/media.phtml"/>
```

app/code/local/AW/Mobile2/etc/config.xml

```
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <aw_mobile2>
                <class>AW_Mobile2_Block</class>
            </aw_mobile2>
        </blocks>
        ...
```

app/code/local/AW/Mobile2/Block/Catalog/Product/View/Media.php

```
class AW_Mobile2_Block_Catalog_Product_View_Media extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Media
{
    /**
     * @return array|Varien_Data_Collection
     */
    public function getGalleryImages()
    {
        if ($this->_isGalleryDisabled) {
            return array();
        }
        return $this->_getMediaGalleryImages($this->getProduct());
    }

    /**
     * @param Mage_Catalog_Model_Product $product
     * @return Varien_Data_Collection
     */
    protected function _getMediaGalleryImages($product)
    {
        if (!$product->hasData('media_gallery_images') && is_array($product->getMediaGallery('images'))) {
            $images = new Varien_Data_Collection();
            foreach ($product->getMediaGallery('images') as $image) {
                if ($image['disabled'] && !$this->_isBaseImage($image, $product)) {
                    continue;
                }
                $image['url'] = $product->getMediaConfig()->getMediaUrl($image['file']);
                $image['id'] = isset($image['value_id']) ? $image['value_id'] : null;
                $image['path'] = $product->getMediaConfig()->getMediaPath($image['file']);
                $images->addItem(new Varien_Object($image));
            }
            $product->setData('media_gallery_images', $images);
        }

        return $product->getData('media_gallery_images');
    }

    /**
     * @param array $image
     * @param Mage_Catalog_Model_Product $product
     * @return bool
     */
    protected function _isBaseImage($image, $product)
    {
        return (strcasecmp($product->getImage(), $image['file']) == 0);
    }
}
```

The file permissions are also correct. Sure I could go with the working solution but I'm really wondering why the aw_mobile2 block type doesn't work. This part wasn't modified and should work though.

I stuck and appreciate any hint. Thanks!

Comment: Just to make sure, did you clear the cache?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Yes, caches are all disabled in backend and I deleted var/cache a couple times. No luck.

Comment: Compilation is disabled?

Comment: Compilation is disabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case "someone" disabled the Module's Output in System > Config > Advanced. Set it to "Enable" fixed the issue. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1):

The only difference between this block and the original block is that it excludes all but the base image:

```
if ($image['disabled'] && !$this->_isBaseImage($image, $product)) {
    continue;
}
```

So it looks like either you don't have a base image set for your products, or it does not recognize them. To debug further, you can add some logging to the `_isBaseImage()` method, like this:

```
protected function _isBaseImage($image, $product)
{
    Mage::log(__METHOD__ . ': ' . $product->getImage() . ' - ' . $image['file']);
    return (strcasecmp($product->getImage(), $image['file']) == 0);
}
```

and then see in `var/system.log` what it actually compares. I guess, the comparision used there is not reliable.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. I added Mage::log to each function in Media.php right after {. But nothing gets logged. So it looks like it does not get used at all.

Comment: Then either the class file cannot be read or the module is not active or you have a typo somewhere in the XML files.